# Trouble logging in

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, okta

I am integrating my asp.net core 6 web application with Okta. I followed all the instructions that they provided, however, I am getting a CORS error when I try to log in.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
 options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn");
})
.AddOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions
{
    // Replace these values with your Okta configuration
    OktaDomain = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaDomain"),
    ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId"),
    ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientSecret"),
    AuthorizationServerId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string> 
    ("Okta:AuthorizationServerId"),
    Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" }
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors();
```

Appsettings.json

```
 "Okta": {
  "OktaDomain": "https://dev-xxxx.okta.com",
  "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.UseCors();` doesn't allow cors yet. You could try

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader());
```

or

```
var OktaDomain = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaDomain");

app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins(OktaDomain)
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader());
```

Another format

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
}));


app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")
```

Comment: It now says."InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.ICorsService' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware"

Comment: @Max I update the answer. You could try the last one.